# Magento 2.3.3 GraphQl Error after upgrade while Compilation

Tags: magento2, setup-di-compile, graphql, magento2.3.3

After upgrade from magento 2.3.2 to 2.3.3 I get this error while Compilation:

> Fatal error: Declaration of Magento\QuoteGraphQl\Model\Cart\SetShippingAddressOnCart::execute(Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Query\Resolver\ContextInterface $context, Magento\Quote\Api\Data\CartInterface $cart, array $shippingAddresses): void must be compatible with Magento\QuoteGraphQl\Model\Cart\SetShippingAddressesOnCartInterface::execute(Magento\GraphQl\Model\Query\ContextInterface $context, Magento\Quote\Api\Data\CartInterface $cart, array $shippingAddressesInput): void in /home/ttu52076/public_html/vendor/magento/module-quote-graph-ql/Model/Cart/SetShippingAddressOnCart.php on line 20

Any help?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Backup and delete the file /vendor/magento/module-quote-graph-ql/Model/Cart/SetShippingAddressOnCart.php

Comment: Thanks, perfect working for me...

Answer (score 0):

The error is pretty specific: the declaration of your class 'method must be compatible with the declaration of the class' method in the interface.

Do you have an override of `Magento\QuoteGraphQl\Model\Cart\SetShippingAddressOnCart`?

Because somewhere in 2.3, the interface for the execute method had an argument that changed from `Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Query\Resolver\ContextInterface` to `Magento\GraphQl\Model\Query\ContextInterface` (see [this change](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blame/64ff8366c004dd0d13b56e5ea1e06e59bcd96cb6/app/code/Magento/QuoteGraphQl/Model/Cart/SetShippingAddressesOnCart.php#L12)). If you ever overrode that method, then you will need to update the $context argument to match the class specified in the interface.