# Magento 2 Compile Void on <directory> in line 20

Tags: error, plugin, compile, putty

I have updated one of my plugin versions (payment plugin) to the most recent version and after running bin/magento setup:upgrade i run the comand : bin/magento setup:di:compile which gives me the following output (see image)[image]

Comment: Backup and delete the file /vendor/magento/module-quote-graph-ql/Model/Cart/SetShippingAddressOnCart.php
you can also refer below link:
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/292453/magento-2-3-3-graphql-error-after-upgrade-while-compilation